# Socket.io: checking if a specific user is in a room already

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create a multiplayer game for 2 users. When the first user joins, he will enter the username of the player he wants to play with, but he will join a room named under his own socket.id since the other player is not online yet. When the second player types the username of the first player, he will be added to the first player's room identified by first player's socket.id.

Hence, when first player enters a room, I store the socket.id in the first user's schema in the db, so that when second player enters first player's username, the server retrieves value of socketId of first player from db. If socketId value is not null, first user is already in room and second player joins the same room and the game can start.

However, **I am wondering if there is an easier way to check whether first player is already in a room and just get the value of first player's roomId**, then I just use `socket.join(firstPlayerRoomId)` when second player enters first player's username (which means I don't have to store the first player's socket.id in the db)

I'm new to socket.io, so I'm not sure if there is a lapse in my concept too. Any advice is welcome, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the simplest solution is that you can use player's name as a room id
`socket.join(firstPlayerName)`, then you can check how many "players" are in the room `io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(firstPlayerName).size`